# Plotting bmi against medical insurance charges

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have a dataframe (from `df.head()`) like this:
[image]

And the dataframe after I converted it to a numpy array.

```py
array([[1.90000000e+01, 2.79000000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 1.68849240e+04],
       [1.80000000e+01, 3.37700000e+01, 1.00000000e+00, 1.72555230e+03],
       [2.80000000e+01, 3.30000000e+01, 3.00000000e+00, 4.44946200e+03],
       [3.30000000e+01, 2.27050000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 2.19844706e+04],
       [3.20000000e+01, 2.88800000e+01, 0.00000000e+00, 3.86685520e+03]])
```

And I have this code, to try and plot `bmi`, against `charges`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))
bmi = df["bmi"]
charges = df["charges"]
ax.plot(bmi, label="bmi")
ax.plot(charges, label="charges")
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

And the result is this:[image]

Now I'm unsure of a few things:

- If I did plot it right, meaning i'm not sure if it's bmi against, charges or charges, against bmi. If I did do `ax.plot(bmi, charges)` together I would get this:

[image]

- Or the values of bmi are so small as compared to charges if you compare `bmi[0]` and `charges[0]`, which is why bmi is seen as a straight line due to the very small values.
- I'd expect the higher the BMI the higher the insurance charges. But when I look at the BMI closest to 34, the charges are quite low as compared to the bmi of the person that is less than 24. And I'm not too sure how to interpret the graph.

Comment: You have 5 values for charges but only 4 for bmi. Why is that?

Comment: That is my bad. It's meant to be matching. Let me edit the question.

Comment: I have posted a solution. Does that answer your query?

Comment: I'm reading it. I'll comment on your answer when I'm done.

Comment: "I'd expect the higher the BMI the higher the insurance charges."  You simply do not have enough data to make that kind of determination.  Cf. e.g. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5615521/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation of `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) , you can find that the first argument is the independent variable (x axis variable) and the second argument is the dependent variable (y axis variable).

As per your question, I understand that you wish to visualise how the insurance charges changes with respect to the bmi. In that case, `charges` would be on the y-axis and `bmi` would be on the x-axis.

## Case 1:

If you do not want to preserve the actual order in the list, then you need to sort both of the lists in ascending order to obtain a linear correlation as you expect like below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

bmi = [33.770, 33.000, 22.705,  28.880]
charges = [16884.92400, 1725.55230, 449.46200, 21984.47061]

plt.plot(np.sort(bmi), np.sort(charges))
plt.ylabel('Charges')
plt.xlabel('BMI')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Here is why your code shows different results:

- In the first code snippet, when you do `ax.plot(bmi, label="bmi"), ax.plot(charges, label="charges")`; it plots both the unsorted lists with respect to the index of the elements as the x axis is not specified.
- In the second code snippet when you do `ax.plot(bmi,charges)` without sorting it would give the result as you obtained (assuming you have same sized lists). But as you mentioned you expect the charges to be higher when the bmi is higher, I assume you would require sorting.

## UPDATE: Case 2:

As per the comments to the initial answer, you are obtaining the data from a dataframe. Ideally in that case, you should sort the dataframe as per the `bmi` values and then take the corresponding `charges` values to plot. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

##### replace this portion with your actual dataframe #######
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['bmi','charges'])
df['bmi'] = bmi
df['charges'] = charges
bmi = [33.770, 33.000, 22.705,  28.880]
charges = [16884.92400, 1725.55230, 449.46200, 21984.47061]
##############################################################

df = df.sort_values('bmi')
plt.plot(df['bmi'], df['charges'])
plt.ylabel('Charges')
plt.xlabel('BMI')
plt.show()
```

Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: The order does matter. I'm grabbing the values of `bmi` and `charges` from a [kaggle dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mirichoi0218/insurance). Here is the first [first five values](https://imgur.com/a/sln0ahZ) with `df.head()`

Comment: Based on the screenshot you have provided, how do you expect the charges to be high when the bmi is high? It's clearly not.

Comment: I just wanted to visualize it, and if there is not linear corrolation how would you suggest that I plot the values out?. But in your edit. Could you re-write it in simpler english?

Comment: Okay, I will post an example of what i meant. Could you please post the `df.head()` as code in the question instead of an image so that I can use that?

Comment: I edited the question as per your request.

Comment: You need to sort both arrays simultaneously. Either via sorting the dataframe or via `np.argsort`: `bmi_order = np.argsort(bmi); plt.plot(np.array(bmi)[bmi_order], np.sort(charges)[bmi_order])`

Comment: I have posted an updated answer. The method @JohanC mentioned is also valid if you want to sort the numpy array instead of the dataframe